# Execute a PHP script file on a remote server without copying it on the remote server

Tags: php, ssh

I have two (linux) servers : A and B

A PHP script is on A, I want to execute it on B but without coping it on B, this script should never exist on B (only in ram), so no "copy on B, exec from ssh command on A, erase on B".

I have ssh keys to access B from A, but not A from B.
Maybe something like :

```
ssh root@B 'php -r ' | echo /myscript/on_serverA
```

or

```
<?php
$script=file_get_contents('executable_php_script');
system('ssh root@IP \'php -r "'.$script.'"\'');
```

Any ideas?

Note: it's a very specific case, so I dont want alternative or security advice.

Comment: I have two cars. I want to drive my fast car  but I also want to not leave the comfy seat of my slow car. How can I drive my fast car without leaving my comfy car? AKA -- why can't you copy the file?

Comment: Because I ask this question .... Of course I "can" copy the file but I dont want to ! (people that have root access to server B but not on server A, shouldn't "steel" the script).

Comment: A better security concept would be to only allow trusted people access the server with root..

Comment: not possible, very specific case, I don't need security advices. I can answer : and if these people have a physical access to the disk , root access is not the only problem, it's just an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can specify the name of a command to run on the remote machine as an argument to ssh
- PHP will execute a script piped into it through STDIN
- Anything piped to `ssh` will be passed into STDIN of the program being run

Thus:

```
ssh example.com php < test.php
```

… will ssh to `example.com`, run `php` there and pipe the contents of `test.php` from the local machine into the remote `php`.

---

With regards to comments on the question: Note that if someone with root access on `example.com` wanted to steal the script they could replace the `php` executable with a wrapper that logs STDIN to a file before forwarding it to the real `php`. This is far from a bullet-proof security measure.